# Building a library consisting of C and C++ files

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

I have a `.so` library where all code was written in plain ANSI C, so compiling it is straightforward. Now, I need to add C++ code in it. What would be the compilation process now?

Do I have to compile C++ files with `g++` and the rest with `gcc`, but what about linking into `.so` file, do I do this with `g++`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes,

- Compile `.c` with `gcc`
- Compile `.cpp` with `g++`
- Link with `g++`

Note:
If a C++ function needs to be invokable from C code, wrap it in `extern "C" { ... }`.

Comment: @rusyx, thanks for feedback. I'm trying this solution, however linking fails: `/usr/bin/ld: license/base64.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.bss' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
license/base64.o: error adding symbols: Bad value`. File `base64.cpp` is c++ code. What am I missing?

Comment: @Mark code that is intended to be used in a shared library should be compiled with `-fPIC`. I assumed your compiler flags already have it, but probably you should review/port relevant compiler flags from CFLAGS to CXXFLAGS.